# JavaScript , D3 bar graph error

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[image]

This is the script/html i am not sure what the problem here is the error I keep arriving at is. I messed around with the y and heigh variables but i am unable to get to a solution. Changed the parameters, changed values but of no avail. Please assist.

```
 Error: Invalid value for attribute y="NaN"

 Error: Invalid value for attribute height="NaN"
```

This is the ERRORS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.bar {
fill: steelblue;
}

.bar:hover {
fill: brown;
}

.axis {
 font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
fill: none;
stroke: #000;
shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
display: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
.rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
.range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom")
.ticks(1)

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left")
.ticks(1.0);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("Unemployment.csv", type, function(error, data) {
if (error) throw error;

x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.letter; })]);
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Frequency");

svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
.enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); });
});

function type(d) {
d.frequency = +d.frequency;
return d;
}

</script>


 Ward,Unemployment
 1,4.5
 2,4.3
 3,4.0
 4,5.7
 5,7.9
 6,5.2
 7,11.0
 8,14.2
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show us some example data?

Comment: Yes, we really need to see `Unemployment.csv` but I'm going to go out on a limb and guess it doesn't have columns of `letter` and `frequency`...

Comment: Can you as well expand the error to trace it and submit it? (Therefore click on the little triangle in front of the Error message and copy everything thats appearing) ;-)

Comment: @MatthewHerbst One second

Comment: @MatthewHerbst I posted the csv data and the screenshot of the error

Comment: I think @Mark called this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you log your data after the `d3.csv("Unemployment.csv", type, function(error, data) {` call you would see that it will contain an array of object with the keys Ward and Unemployment.

However, in several cases such as:

```
x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.letter; })]);
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);
```

And

```
svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
.enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); });
```

your code expects the letter and frequency keys to be present.

Changing these to ward and unemployment would solve this issue